# Como retornar apenas o ultimo resultado de mais de um um campo da mesma tabela?

Tags: php, pdo

Estou tentando fazer um sistema de PM's no script php quero fazer uma listagem de mensagens não lidas porém quero mostrar apenas uma entrada (a ultima) de cada usuário que envio uma mensagem...no script que fiz mostra todas as não lidas porém mostra mais de uma de cada usuário (caso hajam mais de uma).
A grosso modo gostaria que o laço de repetição trouxe-se apenas a ultima PM de cada usuário que envio pm e que ainda não foi lida.

Meu php

```
<?php

$userID = $_SESSION['user_released'];//Declaramos variavel com nome de usuário logado

//Iniciamos a consulta
$Busca = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM pms WHERE status = 0 AND enviador != '$userID' ORDER BY id DESC");
$Busca->execute();

//Iniciamos o laço de repetição   
while($fetch = $Busca->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    //Armazenamos as informações
    $pmID = $fetch['id'];
    $autor =  $fetch['enviador'];
    $data =  $fetch['data'];
    $status = $fetch['status'];

$totali = $Busca->rowCount($autor);

if($totali >= 1){


    //Iniciamos a consulta buscando informação de usuário!
    $Verific = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE `user` = :user");
    $Verific->bindParam(':user', $autor, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $Verific->execute();
    //Iniciamos o laço de repetição
    while($fatch = $Verific->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
         //Armazenamos as informações
        $user = $fatch['user'];
        $autorAvatar = $fatch['avatar'];
    }



}// Fecha "if" !!!


    //Iniciamos a consulta de contagem de pms não lidas!!!
    $BuscaPM = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM pms WHERE enviador = '$autor' AND status = 0");
    $BuscaPM->execute();
    while($fatch = $BuscaPM->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $contagem = $fatch['id'];
    }

    $total = $BuscaPM->rowCount($contagem);

?>
<!-- Trecho HTML para exibir resultados ! -->

<?php
}// Fecha "while" !!!
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Antes de iniciar o seu primeiro while declare a variável `$_autor`, e dentro do laço crie a seguinte verificação antes de buscar e imprimir tudo, ficando assim:

```
// Declare a variável como nula
$_autor = NULL;

//Iniciamos o laço de repetição
while($fetch = $Busca->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    //Armazenamos as informações
    $pmID = $fetch['id'];
    $autor =  $fetch['enviador'];
    $data =  $fetch['data'];
    $status = $fetch['status'];

    if($autor != $_autor) { // comparamos o atual com o anterior
        $_autor = $autor; // se for diferente, armazena na variável para a próxima comparação

        // continue seu código normalmente juntamente com a impressão e feche o if lá embaixo

    } // Fecha o "if"
}// Fecha "while" !!!
```

Assim, a primeira PM de cada usuário será impressa e as restantes serão ignoradas no primeiro IF pois o usuário permanece o mesmo.

Espero que ajude.

Abraços

Comment: Thanks! Fechou todas. era isto mesmo.